# Escape square brackets in Oracle and PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, oracle, postgresql

I'm working on a project where the database could be an instance of oracle or Postgres.

I have the need to write a query with a like that work on both dbs.
The query works on a text column containing a JSON string, for example:

```
{"ruleName":"r2_an","divisionNameList":["div1"],"names":["name1"],"thirdTypeLabels":[],"secondTypeLabels":[],"firstTypeLabels":[]}
```

I need to select the lines with empty thirdTypeLabels.

```
select *
from my_table
where JSON like '%thirdTypeLabels%[]%';
```

On Oracle, for example, does not extract anything, even if in "my_table" there is more than one line matching.

The query is inside a Java software, using JDBC, because we need performace.

Have you any suggestion?

Comment: Use two different queries using the product specific JSON function. You won't find a query that works reliably and fast across both DBMS products. But square brackets don't need to be escaped for a LIKE condition

Comment: The way you put it - sample value & query - **Oracle** returns that row (at least, when I tried it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Postgres you have two choices to make this query work properly:

```
select *
from the_table
where jsonb_array_length(json::jsonb -> 'thirdTypeLabels') = 0;
```

Or - starting with Postgres 12 - using a JSON Path expression

```
select *
from the_table
where jsonb_path_exists(json::jsonb, '$.thirdTypeLabels.size() ? (@ == 0)' );
```

Or use the same JSON path expression as in Oracle:

```
select *
from the_table
where jsonb_path_exists(json::jsonb, '$' ? (@.thirdTypeLabels.size() == 0)');
```

In Postgres you should also use a column defined as `jsonb` rather than `text` (or `varchar`)

Answer (score 3):

You should use a proper JSON parser otherwise there is no guarantee that `%thirdTypeLabels%[]%` will restrict the match of the empty array to the `thirdTypeLabels` key-value pair.

So for Oracle 18c you can use:

```sql
SELECT id,
       thirdTypeLabelsCount
FROM   mytable t
       CROSS JOIN
       JSON_TABLE(
         t.json,
         '$'
         COLUMNS(
           thirdTypeLabelsCount NUMBER PATH '$.thirdTypeLabels.size()'
         )
       )
WHERE  thirdTypeLabelsCount = 0;
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  JSON_EXISTS( json, '$ ? (@.thirdTypeLabels.size() == 0) ' )
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=25ff6abbef39e6735587902483a4b991)

Comment: I would probably use a JSON path expression rather than unnesting the array, But I can't get `where json_exists(json, '$.thirdTypeLabels ? (@.size() == 1)')` to work in Oracle (the path expression works as expected in Postgres). It seems `size()` doesn't really return the length of the array, because `?(@.size() == 3)` also doesn't work in Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, updated with `JSON_EXISTS`. I had the same issue and had to move `.thirdTypeLabels` inside the filter condition.

Comment: Thanks, that expression would work in Postgres as well. `json_value(json, '$.thirdTypeLabels[0]') is null` seems to work as well

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That will also match rows with the JSON `"thirdTypeLabel":[null]` though. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=58f22b17445f96779cbfd0c7d012a47b).